# React App- How to Update Link URL Message

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, create-react-app, manifest.json

I'm trying to update the message "website created using react app" that is shown in this example when sending my URL in chat applications.

Im using the Mars heroku react-app webpack defaults.

Any idea where this setting is?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's in the `index.html` file. This `meta` tag starting at line 8 and ending at line 11. Change the value of `content` attribute (line 10) to whatever you want

[image: React HTML head]